# Proper way to handle a list hierarchy

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, listactivity

I want to ask a general question about the proper way to handle a list with a hierarchy. The way I am doing it now is by calling the same activity with a bundle to handle the next query so I can drill down into the list. I am wondering if there is a better way to deal with lists like mine. Should I use multiple activities? (don't know the depth of the list) or just requery my data when a user selects a list item. The problem with this solution is remembering the list item that was selected and the back button on the phone. I am sure I am missing something obvious but I'm new to Android. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. So here is what I do now:

1. Query the data and display the list in `MainActivity` with with the root items.
2. User clicks on one of the items, get the index of that item and call `MainActivity` with a bundle that contains the index of the item selected.
3. Query the data with the new item and display the new list in `MainActivity`.
4. rinse and repeat...

Also my list is more then two levels deep so I thing the `ExpandableListView` is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons why `ExpandableListView` supports only two levels of in depth, is because its *very* hard to make n-level tree to be user-friendly. Just imagine the mass on user's screen if he or she goes to 5th level.

But, nevertheless, here is the approach I would take. I haven't implemented it yet, but this should be doable.

1. Introduce "Navigation Bar" at the top (like Windows Explorer has, or some sites have):

   > Root > item 1 > subitem 2 > ...
2. Use `Expandable list to show current level and the next level.
3. If user clicks on the item you will invalidate data and re-fill `ExpandbleListView` with next levels.

Her is an example:

```
> Root 
---------------
Item 1
   Subitem 1
   Subitem 2
   Subitem 3
Item 2 
   Subitem 4
   Subitem 5
Item 3
   Subitem 6
```

User clicks on `Subitem 4` and sees:

```
> Root > Item 2
---------------
Subitem 4
   SubSubItem 1
   SubSubItem 2
   SubSubItem 3
Subitem 5
   SubSubItem 4
   SubSubItem 5
```

This is not trivial to implement, but shouldn't be too hard. This gives navigation inside one Activity and uses highly optimized `ExpandableListView` control. You only need to implement custom adapter.

Comment: I also should have said that I don't need or want to show the parent in the list. In other words, as your example shows, I don't need to show Item 1, 2 or 3 in the list. When they click on the Item 1 I was just showing a list of the all the items in Item 1. When they hit the back button I would show Item 1, 2, and 3. Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually the more I read your comment, you're really not doing anything different then I am. Are you suggesting that I recursively call this activity or requery. I'm still looking for a technical answer and not so much the UI. thanks

Comment: The idea was to re-fresh same `ExpandableListView`. Its different in that it does not build task with potentially large amount of activities in it.

Comment: Hi there! Im currently having the need to implement a Tree like widget and this might be the solution, can you elaborate on how to refresh the navigation bar, since you said that you only need to implement the adapter???

Answer (score 1):

If your hierarchy is not deep, with 2 levels only, use an `ExpandableListView`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that my list is more then two levels deep. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is just a comment, not an answer. I think this is an issue in mobile - like apps to expose a deep hierarchy of objects. But I like the design you draw in ascii just above with a breadcrumb and an expandable list to go to next level of depth. Seems relatively easy ti plement, managing cursors, get them from a child, and so on, with textviews or buttons for each element of the breadcrumb trail.